# Predicate which results all objects which are not present in a Too many relation?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

This is the structure of my table.For some particular contacts(depends not the value of 'type') some contacts are added to the members.
I want a query for a group which displays all the contacts(group object) which are not in its members.Following query gives all the members which are in its members 
`[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(members CONTAINS %@)",currentGroup]`
I tried
 `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (members CONTAINS %@)",currentGroup]`

but no luck[image]

Answer (score 0):

To fetch all groups that are not related to `currentGroup` via the "members" relationship,
you need a predicate with a SUBQUERY:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(members, $m, $m == %@).@count == 0", currentGroup]
```

(The reason is that "NOT ANY ..." does not work correctly, which seems to be a Core Data bug).

But note that you have defined the "members" relationship as inverse relationship to itself, which means that it is *symmetric:* "A is member of B" implies "B is member of A".

If that is not indented, you need two separate relationships: A to-many relationship "members", and an inverse relationship "memberOf", which can be to-one or to-many (dependent on whether a group can be member of multiple groups or not).

Then you have to use the inverse relationship to fetch all groups that are not
members of the current group. If the inverse relationship is to-many that would be

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(memberOf, $m, $m == %@).@count == 0", currentGroup]
```

and if the inverse relationship is to-one, then simply

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"memberOf != %@", currentGroup]
```